# Renewal Process where $N(t) + 1 \sim Geometric(exp(-t))$

Tags: renewal-processes

I have the following question in my homework:
$N(t)$ is a renewal process where $L(N(t) + 1) = \operatorname{Geometric}(\exp(-t))$. Find $E[T_1]$ and $E[T_2]$.

However, I'm not sure where to start in order to solve this question. I do know that:

> $\lbrace N(t) = k-1\rbrace = \lbrace T_{k-1} \leq t\rbrace \cap \lbrace T_{k} > t \rbrace$

Me and my teammate have already attempted something for $E[T_1]$, however, I don't use the fact that $L(N(t) + 1) = \operatorname{Geometric}(\exp(-t))$, so I'm not entirely convinced of my answer. My answer is the following:
$P[T_1 > t] = P[N(t) = 0] = e^{-t}$
$P[T_1 < t] = F_{T_1}(t) = 1 - e^{-t}$
$f_{T_1} = \dfrac{d}{dt}F_{T_1}(t) = e^{-t}.$

Therefore, $T_1$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda = 1$ and $E[T_1] = 1/\lambda = 1$.

I still haven't managed to figure something out for $E[T_2]$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @cpiegore I just did the edits  you mentionned! Sorry for the poor question, I'm not used to using this site.

Comment: What exactly does e.g. $L(N(t)+1)$ denote?